# Array to string conversion

Tags: laravel

Hola estoy tratando de ingresar un dato a un campo de mi base de datos en laravel, el problema es que me sale **Array to string conversion** el codigo es el siguiente:

```
$credentials='Lab Catálisis';
    if ($credentials =='Lab Catálisis') {
        $lab = new tbl_lab();
        $lab->lab_ceco = $request->ceco;
        $lab->lab_direccion = $request->direccion;
        $lab->lab_lider = $request->lider;
        $lab->lab_usu_id = DB::select("SELECT max(usu_id) FROM tbl_usuario");
        $lab->save();
        return view('login');
    }
```

El **DB** me trae el dato como un arreglo, como podria convertir ese arreglo que me trae la consulta a un entero para poder ingresarlo a mi campo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se te ha olvidado recoger el dato de tu consulta a la base de datos:

```
$lab->lab_usu_id = DB::select("SELECT max(usu_id) FROM tbl_usuario");
```

Debes recogerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$lab->lab_usu_id = DB::select("SELECT max(usu_id) FROM tbl_usuario")->first();
```

De todas formas, te aconsejo que utilices el orm de laravel; **eloquent**, con eloquent sería algo así:

```
$lab->lab_usu_id = tbl_usuario::max('usu_id');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

En este caso no es necesario usar una consulta *raw*, puedes usar los métodos equivalentes del query builder:

```
$lab->lab_usu_id = DB::table('tbl_usuario')->max('usu_id');
```

Si por algún motivo dicho método no entregara el dato único, puedes acceder al dato con sintaxis de objeto o array,